# realloc() отказывается выделять память. В чем может быть дело?

Tags: c, память

Пишу лабораторку, при перевыделении памяти происходит ошибка:

```
a.out: realloc(): invalid old size: 0x089d4008
```

Код, где выделяется память, такой:

```
graph = (vertex*) malloc(sizeof(vertex)*(N+1));
    res = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
    for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        graph[i].color = 0;
        graph[i].num_edges = 0;
        graph[i].max_edges = 5;
        graph[i].edges = (edge*) malloc(sizeof(edge)*graph[i].max_edges);
        graph[i].value = i;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        int temp1, temp2;
        scanf("%d %d", &temp2, &temp1);
        if(graph[temp1].num_edges >= graph[temp1].max_edges)
        {
            graph[temp1].max_edges *= 2;
            graph[temp1].edges = (edge*) realloc(graph[temp1].edges, graph[temp1].max_edges);
        }
        graph[temp1].num_edges += 1;
        graph[temp1].edges[graph[temp1].num_edges - 1].to = graph+temp2;
    }
```

В чем ошибка, не понимаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, потому что вы в первом цикле используете итерацию с 1 вместо 0.
temp1 какое значение принимает?

Comment: Вводимые значения temp1 и temp2 надо бы проверять на то, что они ссылаются на уже инициализированные элементы массива graph. У Вас нулевой и N-ый элементы не инициализируются в первом цикле, в них мусор. Если в temp1 ввели 0, то это все объясняет.

Comment: Дело оказалось не конкретно в этом месте, но рядом. Большое спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

А malloc-то корректно сработал? Нечего realloc'ить, если malloc не отработал корректно.